# Assigning variables inside remote shell script execution over SSH

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, amazon-ec2

I am trying to execute some shell script on a remote server via SSH.

Given below is a code sample:

```
ssh -i $KEYFILE_PATH ubuntu@$TARGET_INSTANCE_IP "bash"  << EOF
#!/bin/bash
cat /home/ubuntu/temp.txt
string=$(cat /home/ubuntu/temp.txt )
echo $string
EOF
```

cat prints the expected result but
`$string` prints nothing.

How do I store the return value of `cat` in a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the content of Here doc literal otherwise they will be expanded in the current shell, not in the desired remote shell.

Quote `EOF`:

```
ssh .... <<'EOF'
...
...
EOF
```

Comment: tried that out !! no luck !!

Comment: @Silent_Rebel Where is `/home/ubuntu/temp.txt` file located? Local or remote?

Comment: its there on the remote server..

Comment: I think that was the tweak.. It is working now .. thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply do this:

```
ssh -i $KEYFILE_PATH ubuntu@$TARGET_INSTANCE_IP "bash"  <<'_END_'
    cat /home/ubuntu/temp.txt
    string=$(cat /home/ubuntu/temp.txt)
    echo $string
_END_
```

`<<'_END_' ... _END_` is called a [Here Document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) literal, or "heredoc" literal. The single quotes around `'_END_'` prevent the local shell from interpreting variables and commands inside the heredoc.

Answer (score 0):

The intermediate shell is not required (assuming you use `bash` on the remote system).
Also you dont have to use an intermediate *HERE-DOC*. Just pass a multiline Command:

```sh
ssh -i $KEYFILE_PATH ubuntu@$TARGET_INSTANCE_IP '

cat /home/ubuntu/temp.txt
string=$(cat /home/ubuntu/temp.txt )
echo $string
'
```

Note I am using single quotes to prevent evaluation on the local shell.